# Grouping list of events by quarters of the year 2021

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, group-by

I have this schema

| Name | type | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dt | Varchar(19) | event timestamp |
| type | Varchar(64) | Event type |

And this sample table

| dt | type |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-09-08 19:35:17 | other |
| 2020-12-14 12:07:44 | buy |
| 2021-07-08 14:35:25 | sell |
| 2021-10-15 17:07:30 | buy |
| 2021-12-08 06:35:18 | other |
| 2022-12-14 12:07:44 | buy |
| 2022-09-08 19:35:17 | other |
| 2022-12-14 12:07:44 | sell |

I have group the data by quarters in year 2021 and count the each type in each quarter. Query should produce the following output:
(this may be inconsistent with the sample table, this is just for example)

| period | events |
| --- | --- |
| Q1'21 | other=1; sell =1; buy =3 |
| Q2'21 | buy = 1 |
| Q3'21 | sell = 2; other = 4 |

Q1'21 means quarter 1 2021 and  events column counts the types in each quarter.

I am thinking to use CASE WHEN for period column, but have no idea how to write query for events column.
How can I write query for events column?

Comment: Why do you store timestamps in a varchar column? Doesn't SQL Server have any suitable date/time data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you need to do here is first `COUNT` the number of instances per quarter, year and type and then string aggregate afterwards.

This *assumes* you are on a supported version of SQL Server. If you *can't* use `STRING_AGG` due to using a much older version of SQL Server, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method for your string aggregation.

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, dt) AS Year,
           DATEPART(QUARTER,dt) AS Quarter,
           type,
           COUNT(*) AS COUNT
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, dt),
             DATEPART(QUARTER,dt),
             type)
SELECT CONCAT('Q',Quarter,'''',RIGHT(Year,2)) AS Period,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(type,'=',Count),';') AS Events
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Quarter,
         Year;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3fS360Qc)

Comment: I have taken database systems course in university, but have not learned writing complex sql queries. Can you recommend any book to learn this advanced stuff?

Comment: [so] Isn't the right site for tool/book/etc recommendations, @azizalizada . (Plus none of my T-SQL knowledge is from books.)